# Change Chart Series dynamically VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to achieve dynamically chart Time Series

To do this I am copying Dates and Profit from Data Orders from my raw data to another sheet where I will use it to dynamically create chart.

But it is giving me an error. near the line where I am creating range, is there a better way to do this ?

```
Sub ChartDataSeries()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set ws = Sheets("Data - Orders")
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet10")
    ws.Range("C:C").Copy 'Source Copy Order Date
    ws1.Activate
    ws1.Range("B1").Select 'Paste Order Date
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    ws.Range("I:I").Copy 'Copy Profit Series
    ws1.Activate
    ws1.Range("C1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste ' Paste Profit Series
    ws1.Range("B1").Select
    Set rng = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select ' Error Ocurring here
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 7").Activate
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source: rng.Select
    'ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range("Order Date")
    'ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Range("Profit")



End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better if you stay away from all this `Activate`, `Select`, `Selection`, `ActiveChart`, etc..

Replace the following 4 lines:

```
ws1.Range("B1").Select
Set rng = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select ' Error Ocurring here
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 7").Activate
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source: rng.Select
```

With these 2:

```
Set Rng = ws1.Range(ws1.Range("B1"), ws1.Range("B1").End(xlToRight))
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 7").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Rng
```

Comment: @avabhishiek you can't `Set` a `Range` object, and `Select` it at the same line. You need 1 line to `Set`, and you realy don't need to `Select` it to use it as a Chart's `SetSourceData`

Comment: @avabhishiek please mark this as "ASNWER", you have many post lately you don't five credit to people who helped you

Comment: sorry about that , I have marked it as answer , thanks for the help